# One table per database

Tags: mysql, database

I have the following mySql setup:

A database, `player_db`, that contains one table named `player`. `player`has three columns: `id`, `alias` & `score`.

A second database, `match_db`, that contains one table named `match`. `match`has 6 columns. For instance: `id`, `player1`, `player2` & `outcome`.

I've used two databases to be able to locate them on dedicated servers if that need should arise. I don't really like the fact that my tables are named as its database. Have I missed something?

To me, it seems that one table per database must be a very common use case. So common, that there should be something like a 'default table', but I've not found that concept. So maybe I've designed my system incorrectly?

Comment: The more common solution would be to have a single database (let's call it game_db) and have several tables associated with the database, player, match, etc.  As others have indicated, having multiple databases causes a few issues, including but certainly not limited to making your queries more complicated than they need to be, and if you're storing them on separate physical servers, this can also pose network infrastructure related issues as well.  If you don't have a need to do so, avoid doing that at all costs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think using one table per database is as common as you think. 
This will make it more difficult to join tables and do more complicated data operations.
I think a better solution would be to use only one database, and scale when necessary. There are also other ways to scale: Using indexes, and using hardware and loadbalancing.

I think splitting the data up like this will actually make your nworsen program's performance. You know have to connect to two servers. 
If you are worried about diskspace, it is pretty cheap these days. If you are worried about concurrency and availability, you'd probably want the entire database on multiple servers.

MySQL, nor any other SQL Database has a default table, as far as I know.

Comment: I plan to run the setup on EC2 servers on Amazon Web Services. I have a PHP front-end, which I guess scales easily by adding EC2 nodes. No doubt that two databases will oppose more load than one, but my thinking was that I could run each DB on a separate EC2 node and hence gain scalability. But do you mean that I can run ONE database on MULTIPLE EC2 servers? Finally, I hear what you're saying. I will put the tables into one database.

Comment: If you are running your server on EC2 anyway, why don't you just use Amazon RDS? 
https://aws.amazon.com/rds/

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a question for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/
than it is stack overflow. I will tell you this. One table per database is not common, nor is it good design. I have to imagine that whatever your circumstance, you can avoid having to use a separate database for each table.

More to your question, no I don't believe mysql has a default table concept.

Comment: You're right about programmers.stackexchange.com. Will use that next time. And I will put all tables in one database... :)